Are there natural or canonical versions of sum, difference, and/or arithemtic mean in projective space? (or analogues)
I'm thinking of how to add/subtract/average vectors that live on the surface of the sphere in 3D space.  It seems like there's not an obvious way that they should be combined.  You could do it in the 3D space and project back onto the sphere, but that seems wrong.
An answer that covers this case is great; I don't necessarily need the more general version.

You can do a kind of "interpolation" by following a shortest-path geodesic with unit speed from one point to another. On the sphere, this geodesic is unique unless the points are antipodal. This spherical interpolation is common enough to have its own name: slerp. Any well-behaved addition/subtraction would imply a Lie group structure on the sphere, which is impossible for $S^2$ (the 3D sphere).
